# Alternate character colors in the text of my h1 elements

Tags: html, css

I'd like to have the character colors of the text inside my `h1` tags inside my elements of class `outerdiv` to alternate between red and blue. Is this possible using CSS selectors? Obviously I can come up with a brute force method, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't think there are any css selectors to do this cross browser. Your best bet is to wrap every other letter with a span and give that sapn the alternate colour

Comment: the best way to do this is using <span> tags

Comment: https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js/ is a a plugin which converts your characters into spans, and can do more stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with  tags. Imagine you have a paragraph

```
<p> 
    <span class="one">H</span> 
    <span class="one">E</span> 
    <span class="one">l</span>
    <span class="one">l</span>
    <span class="one">o</span>
</p>
```